# Cannot work with XML file. InputStream is null

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

What am I doing wrong here? I am getting the error there there is nothing in the input stream when that is not the case. The file is there and it is titled correctly. I want to grab the ip addresses i have put in my XML file. Is there a better way to parse in the file instead of `dBuilder.parse(XMLReader.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Tools\\CLA\\test.xml"));` ?

I am experiencing this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.Intel.ameier.XMLparser.TryXML(XMLparser.java:17)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class XMLparser {

    protected void TryXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = dBuilder.parse(XMLReader.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Tools\\test.xml"));
        document.normalize();

        NodeList rootNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("info");
        Node rootNode = rootNodes.item(0);
        Element rootElement = (Element)rootNode;
        NodeList compList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("computer");
        for(int i = 0;i < compList.getLength(); i++){

            Node computer = compList.item(i);
            Element compElement = (Element)computer;

            Node theIP = compElement.getElementsByTagName("ipaddress").item(0);
            Element theIpElement = (Element)theIP;

            System.out.println("The comptuer ip is : " + theIpElement.getTextContent());


        }


    }


}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
    <testsuite>
        <name></name>
    </testsuite>
    <computer>
        <ipaddress>111.11.11.6</ipaddress>
    </computer>
    <computer>
        <ipaddress>111.11.11.5</ipaddress>
    </computer>
    <computer>
        <ipaddress>111.11.11.3</ipaddress>
    </computer>
</info>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with XML. You're using `Class.getResourceAsStream`, which is meant to get a resource to be loaded from the classpath for that class's class loader... but you're passing in a *filename* instead.

If you want to create an input stream for a file, just use `FileInputStream`:

```
Document document = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("C:\\Tools\\test.xml"));
```

Or better, in order to close the stream:

```
Document document:

try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Tools\\test.xml")) {
    document = dBuilder.parse(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Youtube(where i was getting this info) is great for learning but it will only get you so far....

Comment: Thx, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It indeed has nothing to do with XML and Jon's answer is satisfactory.

However, the explanation is inaccurate. One can use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to load arbitrary files. There are situations when `Class.getResourceAsStream` is the preferred way of loading resources.

The issue here is that `Class.getResourceAsStream()` interprets its parameter as relative to each path in the classpath, and does not understand the absolute path that was passed here. It can only "see" files that are in the classpath.

You can try adding `C:\Tools\CLA` to your classpath and then just use

```
getResourceAsStream("/test.xml");
```