# Illegal Argument Exception while Reading XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I wrote this while following a video tutorial. The tutorial showed the same thing but got no error!

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory bf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = bf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //says input stream cannot be null
        Document d = db.parse(XmlReader.class.getResourceAsStream("XMLFile.xml")); 

        d.normalize();
```

When I run the program, it says that the input stream cannot be null for the statement indicated statement but, its **not** null!. The file path is correct! Is there something I'm missing? Is there a problem with eclipse or XMLfiles or something?

## Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at io.XMLFileReading.main(XMLFileReading.java:27)
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
 at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
 at io.XMLFileReading.main(XMLFileReading.java:27)

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997031/cannot-work-with-xml-file-inputstream-is-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like using **FileInputStream** would do the job (rather than XmlReader.class.getResourceAsStream()).

```
Document document = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream("XMLFile.xml"));
```

See similar question and accepted answer here: [Cannot work with XML file. InputStream is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997031/cannot-work-with-xml-file-inputstream-is-null)